# Как сделать дробные значения CSS-свойства в цикле for предпроцессора Sass?

Tags: css, sass, компиляция, scss, препроцессор

Есть цикл for,который после компиляции создает нужные мне классы:

```html
$metric_mt: mt;
$metric_mb: mb;

@for $i from 1 to 35 {
    .#{$metric_mt}-#{$i}{
        margin-top: 0rem + $i;
    }
}

@for $i from 1 to 35 {
    .#{$metric_mb}-#{$i}{
        margin-bottom: 0rem + $i;
    }
}
```

Но значения свойства margin-bottom выставляются с шагом в 1, то-есть 1-2-3 rem и т.д. , то мне не нужно.

```css
.mt-1 {
  margin-top: 1rem; }

.mt-2 {
  margin-top: 2rem; }

.mt-3 {
  margin-top: 3rem; }

.mt-4 {
  margin-top: 4rem; }
```

Вопрос: Можно ли сделать так, чтобы цикл генерировал css-классы со свойство margin-bottom с шагом в 0.5 , то-есть 0.5 - 1 -1.5rem и т.д?

```css
.mt-1 {
  margin-top: 0.5rem; }

.mt-2 {
  margin-top: 1rem; }

.mt-3 {
  margin-top: 1.5rem; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Решил вопрос:

```
margin-top: (0rem + $i)/2;
```